# encode/decodeURI for URLs with quotes

Tags: html, url, escaping, encodeuricomponent, decodeuricomponent

I'm having trouble displaying links to URLs with quotes in them and can't figure out a solution despite a load of examples on stackoverflow!  Here's the exact string I'm storing in my database (shows Adelaide Antartica)

https://www.google.com/maps/place/67%C2%B007'27.3%22S+68%C2%B008'56.0%22W/@-67.1447827,-68.3886741,71373m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-67.124258!4d-68.148903

When I just try putting that into a href it links to...

https://www.google.com/maps/place/67%C2%B007 (i.e. breaks at the first single quote)

But I try using href="encodeURI(theLink)" or href="encodeURIComponent(theLink)" it links to the same thing (I even tried the decode options in case I was thinking about it the wrong way and had the same problem).

Does anyone have a recommendation on the best way to proceed here?  I even tried the deprecated "escape" function which also won't work for me.  Thanks for any thoughts at all!

(p.s. funnily enough as I'm writing this I see that even Stack Overflow's link is broken in exactly the same way - maybe it's not even possible?!)

---

EDIT: As requested by Clemzd - I'm using d3 to construct the links, so doing this...

```
anElement.append("text").html("<a href='" + myData[i].url + "'> a link name </a>");
```

Works great on everything but links with a single quote regardless of whether I do encodeURI(myData[i].url) or not

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about the technologies you are using in the project? You have to encode your link in html meaning ' and " will be escape by an antislash. It should be done when you put the link in the href

Comment: Thanks for the response Clemzd - no problem - just made an edit to the above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use single quotes to delimit the value of the `href` attribute, so that value cannot contain unescaped single quotes. That's an issue with HTML markup encoding, not URL encoding.

You can either reverse your use of single and double quotes (encoded URLs cannot contain double quotes, but they can contain single quotes) or replace the single quotes in the URL with a character entity like `&#39;`. URL encoding by `%27` would also work, but that's not a standard encoding that `encodeURIComponent` does.

Comment: this fixed the problem - I just switched the double-single quote scheme I was using so that I specified the href with a double!  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your issue. All you need to know is if your input may contains ' then you have to escape this character. Otherwise you will get something like `anElement.append("text").html("<a href='" + https://www.google.com/maps/place/'link + "'> a link name </a>");` That can't be parsed because of the '.

If you are sure that your link will never contains " then change your code and use " instead as a concatenaion operator.

If not, you can escape ' in server side or client side. For example in client side you can do :

```
function escapeJavascript(input){
 return input.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
        .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
        .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
        .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
        .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
        .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
        .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
        .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
}
```

And then use it like this: `anElement.append("text").html("<a href='" + escapeJavascript(myData[i].url) + "'> a link name </a>");`

Comment: thanks Clemzd but I actually couldn't get this working if you just pass my original text straight into the function it returns pretty much the same thing?  i.e. escapeJavascript("https://www.google.com/maps/place/67%C2%B007'27.3%22S+68%C2%B008'56.0%22W/@-67.1447827,-68.3886741,71373m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-67.124258!4d-68.148903")